# Storage Of Large PDF on google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

How do I retrive a large pdf file (file  send through json query on my server)and  How  I save this file  into google Drive but link(store address generated by google drive) store in database. How to perform this task?

Comment: What has this got to do with MySQLi?

Comment: theres plenty of documentation for this task. show us the code you already tried and what is failing after debugging.